# Updating a local database app for Windows Phone 8.1 (Universal)

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I am using a local database (SQLite) in my Windows Phone (Universal) app. I need to push an update for my app.

My question is 'I have a little schema change (added one extra field to the db). So will this change handled by the wrapper I am using (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). Or do I need to write any extra code for updating the schema without losing data.

I found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394022(v=vs.105).aspx). But is this applicable to Windows Phone universal apps using the above SQLite wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what kind of update you're doing.

If you take a look at [the code for the library you're using](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs) you'll notice that `CreateTable` method does the migration by calling `MigrateTable`. This `MigrateTable` method simply checks if there are any new columns which need to be added and then adds them to the table.

```
foreach (var p in map.Columns) {
    var found = false;
    foreach (var c in existingCols) {
        found = (string.Compare (p.Name, c.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
//and so on
```

So if you just want to add new columns without worrying about keys and constraints, then this should be covered by the library. 
You can, after all, test this easily by creating the initial DB and all the tables, and then simulate the update.

Now, for more complex scenarios, there's no such thing as `DatabaseSchemaUpdater` as there was for LINQ to SQL, so you'll have to use another table in your DB called (for example) `_version` which will hold the current database version, and then you would do the schema update based on what the current version is, and the version you're trying to update the database to.